# Right Most line coding needed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Since I am learning Access VBA, I need the coding for the Right most line. This is what the code builder looks like in one of the databases I inherited from work for the letters I need to produce.

All I know is that I had to reduce the integer from 1 to 10 to 1 to 7 to make the gridlines for the hidden fields disappear yet letter is missing the far right vertical line....I tried 1 to 8 for the integer but got an error.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    Dim lDarkGray As Long: lDarkGray = 3355443
    Dim lWidth As Long: lWidth = Me.Width
    Dim lHeight As Long: lHeight = Me.Height
'left most line
    Me.Line (0, 0)-Step(0, lHeight), lDarkGray
'the rest of the vertial lines
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 7 Step 1
        Me.Line ((Me("txt" & i).Left + Me("txt" & i).Width), 0)-Step(0, lHeight), lDarkGray
    Next i
'bottom lines
    Me.Line (0, lHeight)-Step(lWidth, 0), lDarkGray
End Sub
```

Comment: This is to print on 11X17 paper so looks like the line should be at 16.1

Answer (score 0):

Try for i = 0 to 7 step 1, I think the ctrls are 0 indexed?

Comment: Not sure if I am following you? I cannot change the integer because there are fields hidden. Make sense?

Comment: Err not really, can you post a screenshot or something of your layout and the code behind it plz? Struggling to visualise

Comment: how do I post a screenshot here? I have 2 screenshots for you.

Comment: I figured this out...in a VERY HARD WAY Although very easy to do....Basically deleted the columns from the report and renamed the very last column by re-numbering from 10 to 8 (txt8, lbl8) and then in VB, update the integer from 0 to 7 to 0 to 8. Viola!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! :)